# Title Page Setup Question

Tags: vertical-alignment

What packages would I need to setup a title page like this image?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add a minimal working example (MWE) of your current code.

Comment: Try the [`multicol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol?lang=en) package as it looks like you could make your page with two columns. Using `\raggedright` in the first column and `\raggedleft` in the second column will give you the alignment you've shown. Then the usual text sizes and styles should get you the rest of the way, along with some spacing adjustments.

Comment: You don't really need any packages.  A couple of minipages and a rule should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={X[l]|Q[r,10cm]},
    row{1}={ht=3cm}
    }
&\Huge\itshape\bfseries Statement of work\\
&\itshape\huge For\\[1cm]
&\Large Customer XYZ\\
&\Large XXX Renovation and\\
&\Large Logistics SOW\\[8cm]
\textbf{Prepared:}&\\
15 May 2017&\\
&\\
\textbf{Updated:}&\\
28 June 2017&\\[2cm]
\end{tblr}
\newpage
The report text.
\end{document}
```

[image]